# Using md5 byte-wise XOR for TACACS

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I am writing a basic TACACS client module.  I can get the packets on the wire via struct.pack ok, as I've checked against wireshark.  But I am not sure how to handle the byte-wise XOR of the md5 and not even sure if I am creating the hash properly.  The RFCs for TACACS say take specific items from the TACACS header and 'secret key' and encrypt it five times, concatenating the previous hash during each run. See below

```
def encrypt(packet, tac_key):
    key = packet[4:8] + bytes(tac_key, 'utf-8') + packet[:1] + packet[2:3]
    h1 = md5()
    h1.update(key)
    hash = h1.digest()
    previous = h1.digest()

    for i in range(2, 6):
        new = md5()
        key = key + previous
        new.update(key)

        hash += new.digest()
        previous = new.digest()

    return hash
```

The packet has already been run through struct.pack

```
body = struct.pack(fmt, TAC_AUTHEN_LOGIN, TAC_PLUS_PRIV_LVL_USER, TAC_PLUS_AUTHEN_TYPE_PAP, TAC_PLUS_AUTHEN_SVC_LOGIN,
                   user_len, port_len, rem_addr_len, data_len, bytearray(user, 'utf-8'),
                   bytearray(port, 'utf-8'), bytearray(data, 'utf-8)'))
```

Is this the correct way to do this or should I not use struct.pack on the body of the packet and just encrypt it?

Comment: [TACACS+ draft rfc](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-opsawg-tacacs-06)

Comment: About the only thing I would note is that the RFC draft seems to use all integer-valued fields (as far as I can tell, this only matters for the session id) in network, or big-endian, byte order.

Comment: Ok, to clarify.  Should I XOR the variable body, which is packed binary data, or should I just XOR the the body as strings.  If I use body an hash for XOR then I have all ints already and no need for to use 'ord' as I have seen done so far.  I also get gibberish after the XOR, which I presume shows the encryption.  By the way, user, port, rem_addr, and data are text not int.

Comment: `key = key + previous` is not correct. `key` should never change, but you should compute `new.update(key + previous)`.

Comment: Bad choice of variable name on my part.  'key' is the seed for the md5 hash, and each subsequent  call the next seed must have the md5 hash concatenated to it.  However, I think I am generating it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I was not generating a new pseudo_pad with server's response header.  Therefore, the response remained obfuscated.

Comment: But now I get Invalid Authentication/Start packet errors but my key is correct.